# How to change background colour of radio button on click (Contact form 7)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm trying to change the background color of the radio button on click (contact form 7)

HTML Code (Contact form 7)

```
<label class="form-label" for="HomeDescription1">
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap HomeDescription">
<span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-radio form-radio-btn" id="HomeDescription1">
</span>
</span>
<span>Single Family</span>  
</label>
```

and here is the CSS Code

```
.form-radio-btn {
    opacity: 0;
}

.form-label {
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
    padding: 50px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
}

.form-radio-btn:checked + .form-label {
    background-color: red;
}
```

by default, it should show green color which is working fine but on click, it should change the color to red which is not working

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your html code is missing input radio? Could you please update the markup correctly

Comment: That's how contact form 7 plugin render or display the markup @ZamAbdulVahid

Comment: I recommand to not use Contact Form 7 because there is a JavaScript issue and it wasn't  updated for the last two month: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/contact-form-7/reviews/?filter=1

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you have added the radio buttons in the following way in you contact form 7 shortcode:

```
[radio your-radio-btn default:1 "Radio 1" "Radio 2" "Radio 3"]
```

Then, use the following css code. Please also refer to this quick [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Yonkov/nwsqtp4o/4/) that I wrote.

```
.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-radio {
    position: relative;
}

/* Container */
.wpcf7-list-item {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.wpcf7-list-item input[type='radio'] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  top: .7em;
  left: 1em;
}

/* On mouse-over, add background color */
.wpcf7-list-item input[type="radio"] + span::before {
  background-color: #2ad587;
  transition: background 0.5s linear;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.5s linear;
}

input[type="radio"] + span::before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0px 12px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: solid 2px #666;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  content: '';
  transform: scale(0.8);
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + span::before {
  content: "\2713";
  color: #fff;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  border: solid #666;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Here is how it looks on my side:

[image: custom radio buttons in contact form 7]